# How to display a list of attachments that are related with a record?

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, fileupload, flow-screen-component, lightning-file-upload

I am looking for a solution to display a list of attachments that are related with a record without allowing the user to delete the existing files and preventing him from uploading files in this screen only, can't restrict the user/profile from uploading a file in general, because he does needs to upload files somewhere else. The solution needs to works in the Experience Cloud. I am writing this thread because I have read so many posts and tried different options and still can't build a solution for this with declarative tools:

***1. Option A:*** I tried adding the Notes & Attachments related list to the page layout. However it is required to remove the 'Upload File' button, which is not possible. I also tried adding a validation rule on the Content Version object. However I would need to write the rule in a way that the rules validatidates against the status of the parent record that is link to the file. That field relationship is not available via the validation rule builder. Option A discarded.
[image]

***2. Option B:*** using the unofficialsf.com [Improved File Upload](https://unofficialsf.com/from-josh-dayment-improved-file-upload-in-flow-screens/) Similar here I could not find an option to remove the option to Upload a File.

[image]

I thought about using the built in validation on the component to prevent the user from uploading a file. But the formula that I wrote did not seem to work. I tried with a 'False' constant, but still did not work. I keeps allowing the user to upload a file.

[image]

Plus the component allows the user to delete a File. I tried a setting that is supposed to prevent Deletion but can't make it work either.

Any ideas? Ultimately I just need a list of links to those files. Is there an alternative and build an HTML table that displays that list of links generated from a text collection?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for very simple solution, Go with Flow data table and display the attachments records related to it in a screen.

[image]

Comment: I tried that but I cant get a clickable link on the Data Table component.